# How to find if a string is in a list or lists in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to process a csv file and want to extract the entire row if it contains a string and add it to an another brand new list. But my approach is giving me all the rows which contain that string whereas I want the unique string row. Let me explain it with an example:

I have the following list of lists:

```
myList = [['abc', 1, 3, 5, 6], ['abcx', 5, 6, 8, 9], ['abcn', 7, 12, 89, 23]]
```

I want to get the whole list which has the string 'abc'. I tried the following:

```
newList = []
for temp in myList:
    if 'abc' in temp:
        newList.append(temp)
```

But this gives me all the values, as 'abc' is a substring of all the other strings too which are in the strings. What is a cleaner approach to solve this problem?

Update:

I have a huge CSV file, which I am reading line by line using `readlines()` and I want to find the line which has "abc" gene and shove the whole line into a list. But when I do if 'abc' in , I get all the other strings which also have "abc" as a substring. How can I ignore the substrings.

Comment: I ran your exact code and `newList` is `[['abc', 1, 3, 5, 6]]`.

Comment: Posted code should work. I'm sure, you have something else going on with your code..

Comment: `if 'abc' in temp[0]:` is probably the mistake, or some other referencing to only the first element

Comment: @timgeb You are right. In this use case, it works, but I have a huge CSV file, which I am reading line by line using readlines() and I want to find the line which has  "abc" gene and shove the whole line into a list. But when I do if 'abc' in , I get all the other strings which also have "abc" as a substring. So I want to ignore the substrings! :(

Comment: @AngelaRoux I have added an answer in regards to your CSV processing. I hope it helps. I would suggest you to rephrase your question and add this comment info to your question which would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment on the question, I think it is straight forward to use `numpy` and `pandas` if you want to process a csv file. Pandas has in-built csv reader and you can extract the row and convert into a list or a `numpy` array in a couple of lines with ease. Here's how I would do it:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("your_csv")
#assuming you have column names.
x = df.loc[df['col_name'] == 'abc'].values.tolist() #this will give you the whole row and convert into a list.
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(df.loc[df['col_name'] == 'abc']) #gives you a numpy array
```

This gives you much more flexibility to do processing. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will update my question. Really helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to append only if the string matches 'abc' and nothing else(e.g. true for 'abc, but false for 'abcx'). Is this correct?

If so, you need to make 2 corrections;

First, you need to index the list, currently temp is the entire list, but if you know the string will always be in position 0, index that in the if statement.(if you don't, either a nested for loop will work)

Second, you need to use '==' instead of 'in'. 'in' means that it can be a part of a larger string, whereas '==' must be an exact match.

```
newList = []
for temp in myList:
    if temp[0] == 'abc':
        newList.append(temp)
```

or

```
newList = [temp for temp in myList if temp[0] == 'abc']
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, as others said it before me.

Part of your question was to get a cleaner code. Since you only want the sub-lists that contain your string, I would recommend to use [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter):

```
check_against_string = 'abc'
newList = list(filter(lambda sub_list: check_against_string in sub_list, myList))
```

`filter` creates a list of elements for which a function returns true. It is exactly the code you wrote, but more pythonic!